# The purpose of using a createAndStart

Tags: anylogic

Hello: I am working on model that adds an agent to a user specified location in main. To keep it simple, the agent is `MyBox`. I have a button control in main that does the following.

```
MyBox b = new MyBox();
b.createAndStart(this);
add_myBoxes();
b.rectangle.setFillColor(randomColor());
b.setXYZ(0, 0, zLoc);
zLoc += 20;
```

I stumbled on a solution, but before I added `b.createAndStart(this)`, I kept getting a NullPointerException. Can someone please provide insight on what this method does? AnyLogic help says it assigns the owner of this agent to the top level agent of the model, which I am assuming is main in this case. Why is that necessary to do if I have added the agent to `myBoxes` population in main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you do not use that function. The `add_myBoxes(...)` function does all that for you, so no need to use it at all.

So in your case, do not use it but ALSO do not use your custom creator `new MyBox()`.

Simply use

```
MyBox b = add_myBoxes();
b.rectangle.setFillColor(randomColor());
b.setXYZ(0, 0, zLoc);
zLoc += 20;
```

and you are good to go

PS: AnyLogic allows you to use many functions that are neither documented nor self-explanatory. However, 99% of the cases you do not actually need them ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your code added the boxes to the population but did not display them. I added a 3D window in my model to view. Any idea why?

Comment: This a different question, please open a new one for that issue. Also, if the reply helped to solve the original issue, please flag it as helpful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . :)